# How to show a custom label with an empty value in an option of select tag in Angularjs in vf page?

Tags: visualforce, angularjs

I hav a problem when I create a picklist with angular in `Visualforce Page`.
The code is below.

**Javascript**

```
$scope.plApp = {countries: ["UK", "AU", "US"], ctry: ""};
```

**Markup**

```
<select class="selCountry" ng-model="plApp.ctry" ng-options="country for country in plApp.countries">
    <option value="">All Countries</option>
</select>
```

**Rendered Markup**

```
<select class="selCountry ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched" ng-model="plApp.ctry" ng-options="country for country in plApp.countries">
    <option value="?" selected="selected"></option>
    <option label="UK" value="string:UK">UK</option>
</select>
```

Which looks like:

[image: wrong!]

Please notes that the first option does not have a label and is just empty!

I want the result to be:

```
<option selected value="">All Countries</option>
```

And look like:

[image: correct]

Why does the rendered markup not match my expected result?

Comment: try with like http://jsfiddle.net/bmleite/gkjve/ or http://jsfiddle.net/Ratan_Paul/kuj1341h/1/

Comment: you need to add All Types option in array options `plApp.countries`

Comment: Sorry for you all, I`m already added two pictures make easy to understand what I want to get!

Comment: Hi Ratan, I tried to do that, but it is still wrong. vf page will rended that value as <option label="All Countries" value="string:All Countries" selected="selected">All Countries</option>, but in fact, this value must be empty. and meanwhile I will use this to make filter, so now I can`t filter anything when I select "All Countries" value. Correct result should to show all records when I select "All countries" value. :(

Comment: Hey @Leisure use like ... in your controller `$scope.plApp = {countries: [
        {
            id: '',
            name: 'All Countries'
        },{
            id: 'UK',
            name: 'UK'
        }, {
            id: 'AU',
            name: 'AU'
        }, {
            id: 'US',
            name: 'US'
        }], ctry: ""};` and in page `<select  ng-model="plApp.ctry" ng-options="country.id as country.name for country in plApp.countries">
</select>`  .... This will solve your problem

Comment: @Ratan, thanks. I got you, but the data from apex are a pure array, not an object array. I tried in local host and it works good, but not in vf page. 

and could I have your skype?

Comment: Sorry @Leisure.. I can't share my skypeId... SO you want to say you can't modify the `countries` array ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34179/discussion-between-ratan-and-leisure).

Comment: Please vote this question to open it if everyone already understood my question, thanks for you all!